# Animation of position via 'vertical-align' change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I change the vertical position of a container by adding/removing classes, which define the verticle-align of the element. So far everything is working. I would like to animate this movement of the element. Is this possible? And if yes, would this be possible with CSS-animations?

**JSFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/j1wxc6a1/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="wrapper" class="col-middle">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="content" class="top-margin">
                <input type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.col-top {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.col-middle {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.top {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#main {
    display: table;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    height: 100% !important;
}
#wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#wrapper').removeClass('col-middle').addClass('col-top');
$('#content').addClass('top');
```

Comment: Your CSS code is not working fine , the .col-top and .col-middle are doing nothing you know that ? http://jsfiddle.net/j1wxc6a1/

Comment: @Diptox: It is just a snippet out of the complete code.

Comment: provide us with the full css code of each element

Comment: @Diptox Updated post and JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j1wxc6a1/1/

Comment: it won't work as an Animation , it will just change the position to the top
http://jsfiddle.net/ubnfmxua/1/ , i think you should go with Margin-top or Top , there will be a progressiv animation

Answer (score 0):

Add this css properties to #wrapper:

`transition-duration:1s;
-webkit-transition-duration:1s;`

and you will get 1 second animation from all style properties change.
Add extra `transition-property: vertical-align;` to play animation only when `vertical-align` changed.

Way without setting transition is:

```
$('#wrapper').animation({'vertical-align': 'top'}, 1000);
```

Comment: It is still just jumping. Don't see an animation.

Comment: he wants it in CSS i think not in jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 Animation:
See Following Example:

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background-color:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {background-color:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
    75%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background-color:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {background-color:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
    75%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

also can use JavaScript.

Comment: I don't know how to use that example in my case - as I'm using the verticle-align property...

Comment: It's simple,read more about CSS3 Animations [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).

Answer (score 0):

it won't work as an Animation , it will just change the position to the top

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ubnfmxua/1/)

```
.col-top {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.col-middle {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.top {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#main {
    display: table;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    height: 100% !important;
}
#wrapper {
    height:300px;
    display: table-cell;
    float: none
    animation: Animate 4s;
    -webkit-animation: Animate 4s;
}

@keyframes example 
{
    from {vertical-align: middle;}
    to {vertical-align: top;}
}
-webkit-@keyframes example 
{
    from {vertical-align: middle;}
    to {vertical-align: top;}
}
```